# Connect to Azure Sql Managed Instance from on-premise SSMS

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am new to Azure. I am currently trying to migrate the on-premise databases to Azure Sql Managed Instance. I created the resources in Azure. I now like to connect to the database that I created from my on-premise Sql client from the organization Dev LAN. What configuration should be implemented to make all developers able to connect to this Azure Sql Instance. My organization does not allow to use public endpoint and use 3342 port. How should I proceed?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If your Managed Instance has its public endpoint disabled, then you'll have to connect to the private IP.

So your options are:

1. Get your network engineers to route your "Dev Lan" to the Azure VNet containing the Managed Instance over a [Site-to-Site VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-configure-s2s-vpn) or [ExpressRoute](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/expressroute/)
2. Set up a [Point-to-Site VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-about) from your client machine to the Azure VNet.
3. Connect over RDP to an Azure VM "jump box" running SSMS in an Azure VNet that can communicate with the Managed Instance.